# Pie Charts con Google Charts

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, google-visualization

Estoy tratando de generar una grafica pie chart con codeigniter y mysql pero me sale estoy error Quisiera su ayuda Aqui esta el codigo;

**chartcontroller.php**

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * 
 */
class ChartController extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('chartmodel', 'chart');
    }

    public function index() {
        $results = $this->chart->get_chart_data();
        $data['chart_data'] = $results['chart_data'];

        $this->load->view('chart', $data);
    }

}

/* End of file ChartController.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/ChartController.php */
```

**chartmodel.php**

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class ChartModel extends CI_Model {

 private $performance = 'cursos';

 function __construct() {

 }

 function get_chart_data() {
     $query = $this->db->get($this->performance);
     $results['chart_data'] = $query->result();



     return $results;
 }   }   /* End of file chartmodel.php */ /* Location: ./application/models/chartmodel.php */
```

**chart.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    [{type: 'string', label: 'Nombre'}, {type: 'number', label: 'Horas'}],
<?php
foreach ($chart_data as $data) {
    echo '[' . $data->nombre . ',' . $data->horas. '],';
}
?>
                ]);
 
                var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

 
               var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
       </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes poner el HTML que generas

Comment: el codigo de la vista esta en chart.php

Comment: hasta ahora me sale asi pero donde esta circulo rojo deberia salir un string ejemplo matematica

Comment: funciona si elimino los nombres en la base de datos y los pongo como enteros pero no deberia ser asi ya que la primera columna debe sen datos string

Comment: Hace unos meses trabajé con php, oracle y highcharts y lo que me funcionó a la perfección fue "armar" una estructura json desde php con los datos que provienen desde la base de datos, y luego, ese json insertarlo en el gráfico que requieras. Nunca he trabajado con google charts, pero al final mi consejo es que trates de usar Json, tal vez te ayude.

Comment: @Kpeski2814 por favor actualiza tu pregunta con una muestra de los resultados obtenidos. No conozco `codeigniter` pero puede ser que el valor `matematicas` no exista en el conjunto de datos o lo estás leyendo de otra columna..,

Comment: @Kpeski2814 el error que te sale en que linea de tu index.php es??

Answer (score 1):

Debes pasarle las String de nombre como string, te lo esta detectando como variable ya que detecta Matematicas y no 'Matemáticas'.

Creo que seria algo así, aunque no soy mucho de tocar PHP:

```
<?php
foreach ($chart_data as $data) {
    echo '[\'' . $data->nombre . '\',' . $data->horas. '],';
}
?>
```

Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

Como ha dicho ReyJuanjo tienes que añadirlo como cadena de texto, es decir tienes que ponerlo entre comillas. Ademas,no debe haber una coma al final del ultimo valor.
Añado el código corregido.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" 
           src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

      <?php
         $arrayToDataTable ="['Nombre', 'Horas']";
         foreach ($chart_data as $data) {
            $arrayToDataTable .= ", ["' . $data->nombre . '","' . $data->horas. '"]";
         }
      ?>

      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         "<?php echo $arrayToDataTable ?>"
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'My Daily Activities'
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
   }
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```